# UITabBarController + autorotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I created an application with a TabBarController using IB who have 4 TabBarItems and so display 4 differents ViewControllers.
To allow a landscape orientation I must add this code in all of my ViewController:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
     return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown ? NO : YES);
}
```

The problem is I don't want for example the secondViewController to autorotate, How can I do that?
Because everytime I delete the code above in one of my ViewController, every ViewControllers not rotate anymore.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Leave the code in there, but you'll want to do one of two things:

1. Disable the non-rotatable tab when showing landscape view OR
2. In the viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear for that tab, force rotation to portrait.

eg:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:YES]
```

Comment: the second method is not working, because shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation work everytime I turn the device. can you tell me how can I do the 1st method? how to disable the non-rotatable tab?

Comment: The second method could work if you return NO when the non-rotatable view is visible.  As for disabling the tab, use the view controller's tabBarItem property and set enabled to false.  Something like nonRotatableController.tabBarItem.enabled = NO;

Comment: not bad for the [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:NO]
 the problem is that all the others elements in the View rotate, the TabBar, the NavigationController and of course the View itself