# Autoresizing failure in a modal NavigationController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, rotation

I've searched Stackoverflow and googled till I'm blue in the face and still can't work this out...

I have a not-too complicated app: a tab bar controller, with one of the root view controllers for a tab being a UINavigationController. A few regular VCs I've written get pushed onto this nav controller in the usual way. One of those VCs has a UIButton which **presents a modal dialog** and that is where I'm having problems.

Here's a picture to help illustrate:

```
UITabBarController
  \---- Tab1 root VC: UINavigationController
       \---- Nav root VC: UIViewController
            \---- ...onto which we push: UIViewController
                 \---- ... on which we present modally: UINavigationController
                      \---- Nav root VC: UIViewController
```

The modal dialog is a UINavigationController and for the rootViewController I have a simple VC that presents a single UIView in it. My VC supports landscape rotation (which the rest of the app doesn't, hence the strategy of presenting it as a modal).

**The problem: upon rotation**, and upon subsequent rotations, the autoresize behaviour is doing something odd for that UIView: **the top of the UIView ends up right against the status bar, i.e. *underneath* the navigation bar**. The left, right, bottom edges are in the correct place.

I've checked and double checked - all my autoresizeMasks look correct, the autoresizesSubviews flags look correct, there's no weird insets set anywhere, my UINavigationController isn't doing anything funky like setting the navbar style to translucent.

I've recreated the situation in a new test app, but omitting the UITabBarController at the top of the heirarchy, and everything behaves as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!

Here's what the issue was:

I am using [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD) to show a progress spinner over the view in my modal.
So in `viewDidLoad` I had:

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:progressHUD];
```

The addition of this HUD component to that view was screwing up the resizing upon rotation; if I instead do the following things work again:

```
[self.view addSubview:progressHUD];
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the important points about `UITabBarController` is that it can support autorotation only if all of its views do as well. This [S.O. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442385/uitabbarcontroller-autorotation) may help finding a way out.

On another note, the height of the status bar for a `UINavigationController` changes between the two modes, so you'll have to adjust for it:

```
 CGRect frame = self.navViewController.navigationBar.frame;
 if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
    frame.size.height = 44;
 } else {
    frame.size.height = 32;
 }
 self.navViewController.navigationBar.frame = frame;
```

EDIT: 
If that does not work, you can try and force the change of device orientation programmatically like this:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight];
```

possibly this will make your main window resize the navigation bar.

Comment: But I'm presenting the troublesome UI in a modal, as I said in my question. Therefore, the UITabBarController doesn't get to veto its rotation. And it *is* rotating; the problem is that the autoresizing of the main view isn't doing the expected thing.

Comment: Also, the resizing of the nav bar is usually handled by the system (and it *is* handled in my problem case) -- it gets shorter in landscape. Setting bounds and frames to hardcoded numbers is usually a sign that either a) you're doing it wrong, and/or b) you're hacking around some iOS bug  :)

Comment: Yeah, you are possibly right on a/b. What I think is that using a UINavigationController/UITabBarController in a modal view is not really well supported, and I was proposing a workaround... if it does not work I added another suggestion...

Comment: I think a UINavigationController in a modal should be fine though? The tab bar controller isn't in the modal.

Comment: Don't know... Do you really need the view to be modal?